# Navigation Controller presented modally is empty 2nd time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to present a `UITableViewController` modally on one of my view controllers which is further embedded in a UITabBarController. The code I am using is -

```
ContactTableViewController *contactsVC=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contact"];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contactsVC];
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
contactsVC.myDelegate = self;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The view is presented just fine the first time I do it but when I navigate to this view again in my app, the view being presented is completely blank.. No navigation bar buttons, no title, nothing..

Can't figure out a reason... Any help is very much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

```
HomeViewController *vc = [[HomeViewController alloc] init]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

This what I do to navigate to that view again while unhiding the tab bar. Home View is the view that presents the Contacts Table View modally.

Comment: I think you forgot to add `contactsVC` to `navController`.

Comment: Why does it happen to work first time then? Because it's set as the root view controller?

Comment: how you are navigating again to that vc ?

Comment: HomeViewController *vc = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: HomeViewController is the view which presents the ContactsTableViewController

Comment: better if you post descriptive code or come in chat

Comment: Not really familiar with how to get into a chat